# Left zero padded format numbers

Tags: java, format, zero-padding

I want to format 4-digit numbers with left padded zeros and 5-digit numbers with no leading zeros so when e.g:

- I insert 124 it is formatted to 0124.
- 30 is formatted to 0030.
- When number >9999 then it has no zero padding.

I tried `String.format("%05d", Integer.parseInt(something));`

but when I format 124, I get 00124

Comment: Yes, sorry let me rephrase it

Comment: You want to have a **4** digit number, but for some reason decided to specify **5** in your format string…

Comment: The user enters 1 digit should format to : 000x, 2 digits to: 00xx, 3 digits to: 0xxx, 4 digits to xxxx, 5 digits to xxxxx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `%04d` instead:

- `0` indicates what you're using to pad;
- `4` is the width of the number (you had `5` before);
- `d` represents an integer (incl. byte, short, int, long, bigint).

```
String.format("%04d", Integer.parseInt(something));
```

Comment: Will this format a 5-digit number correctly? What if I enter 10000?

Comment: You can do `String.format("%04d", Integer.parseInt(something)).substring(0,4);` to have a 4 letter String

Comment: @happysongs I think, you answer is already what the OP wants. They don’t want `substring(0,4)`